# Writiing to a SERVER file using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, save, loading

Tried all solutions.. none of them seem to work for me.

Basically, I have this website **UPLOADED** on the server that has a button which when clicked does a simple task of loading a file from the server, displaying it  and adding +1 to it and then saving it back.

The main question now arises, I tried all the ways which I could find on the net to save the file back but it doesn't seem to work for me. Any specific advice on how can I fix this issue using  JS?

**UPDATE - One way I am using is - (Doesn't work tho)**

```
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var s = fso.CreateTextFile("TOTAL.TXT", true);
            var text = test1;
            s.WriteLine(text);
            s.Close();
```

Where test1 is the name of the variable which i am trying to write.

Comment: May you post some of the `ways which I could find on the net to save the file back` so we know what you exactly did and how we could help you?

Comment: by pure JS do you mean getting rid of jQuery from the client code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: When you have tried **all** solutions, then there is no solution left. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr - should put that on a t-shirt :p

Comment: This can not be done in JS, as JS can not write to files, neither on the client nor on the server side (unless we're talking about node.js).

Comment: Javascript is server sided (or I would expect a nodeJS tag) and client sided javascript on it's own can't write to a server. You can make a HTTP request, using ajax for example and ash a PHP file to do what you want to do.

Comment: it can't be done using pure javascript. You must have a server-side script to handle your request

Comment: it can be done in pure JS both client and server, if the server happens to be nodejs (or something like it) ... I think the question may be how to remove jquery from the client side code, server side is untouched (that's my opinion - would be nice if the OP came back to clarify some of these questions from well intentioned folk)

Comment: @TonyVincent Like what?

Comment: Like a php script

Comment: @TonyVincent or javascript (nodejs)

Comment: Now you would confuse someone here. Now js is server-side too? Whoa! :D @JaromandaX

Comment: @eisbehr - nodejs can be used to write fairly decent server side code (I'm not really sure how to take your comment to be honest)

Comment: yes nodejs is awesome

Comment: @JaromandaX - It was a bit of irony, sorry. I think it will confuse him even more, that js can be server-side too. ;)

Comment: Edited question further. Please have a check once again. Thanks...

Comment: @eisbehr - all good - the problem is, the question is extremely unclear

Comment: @AkshitSharma - did you say you have jQuery that works as you want? because jQuery is just sugar for javascript - if it can be done with jQuery, it already **is** being done with javascript. There's no need for activex (IE7 is dead anyway) - jquery doesn't need it, therefore you don't. Please clarify what **the issue actually is**

Comment: Is this possible via AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you have php on server try this js

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , 1);
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open( 'post', '/path/to/php', true );
xhr.send(data);
```

php script

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];
$fname = "filname.txt"

$file = fopen("upload_or_whatever_path/" .$fname, 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");// open file
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for being so nice to answer this question without OP showing any effort. Nice and simple answer as well

Comment: Finally! I got what to do now.. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shared belongs to the [Windows Scripting Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) platform. That's an automation solution for Microsoft Windows that's by no means intended for public web sites.

File upload implementation requires a proper server-side programming language (PHP, JSP, Node...). Client side code can be as simple as a static HTML form.